# getCorrelationId removed in SI

Tags: spring-integration

Not sure if this was done intentionally but getCorrelationId is not available anymore in MessageHeaders class. Some of the other methods like getTimestamp is still there. In fact the constant CORRELATION_ID isnt available anymore either so there is no good way to get the correlation id other than `message.getHeaders().get("correlationId")`. Seems a bit raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-3.0-to-4.0-Migration-Guide) needs to be a little clearer, but when the core messaging classes moved to the Spring Framework in 4.0, a new `MessageHeadersAccessor` class was introduced, together with `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor` for integration-specific headers; with the new protocol being...

`new IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor(message).getCorrelationId()`

...but the migration guide does say that the header constants and typed accessors were moved to those classes.

I have made some minor tweaks to the wiki; let us know if more clarity is needed.